# Trying to check if a user input is or is not an integer, then running a while loop

Tags: python, integer

I've been attempting to work on an assignment for my compsci class, and one of the requirements is that, if a user input is not an integer to print an error message and close out of the program. I've tried using the isnumeric() operator in tandem with an if statement, but it's giving me the same error given if you, for example, typed a non integer into an int(input( statement.
The assignment wants us to have a user input numbers, add them to a list, until 0 is inputted, then print the sum of all list items.

[image: This is my current code attempting to utilize isnumeric()]

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as the code, as text in your post itself.

Comment: The `int()` function will get an error if the input is not numeric. You need to call `isnumeric()` first, and only call `int()` if it succeeds.

Comment: Or use `try/except` to catch the error.

Comment: try: int() except ValueError: You should find many examples if you search here.

Answer (score 0):

The error message should be different if you enter a letter or a number.
Something like this for the first:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'

and this for the second case:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'q'

Try to derive your desired solution from this:

```
user_input = input ("Enter your Age")
try:
    val = int(user_input)
    print("Input is an integer number. Number = ", val)
except ValueError:
    print("That was not a number, at all.")
```

Exceptions are a great way to deal with problems in python.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the code will loop until you input an integer.

```
while True:
    try:
        number= int(input("Give me a number? "))
        break
    except:
        print("Invalid input!")
print(f"The number is: {number}")
```